# Xcode 7 update completes but Xcode 6.4 remains

Tags: xcode7, xcode6.4

I updated my Xcode to 7 but when I open it , it shows me the Xcode 6.4. I also tried to restart my system and also moving my Xcode (both) to trash but it didn't work. Can someone tell me why?