# Xcode 6.4 updated to 7.1 version but Xcode still shows 6.4

Tags: xcode6, xcode7

I have recently updated Xcode 6.4 to 7.1 but after successful update it still shows 6.4. Anything else I need to take care while upgrading to 7.1 ?
My Mac OS version is 10.10.5  .Please give some assistance , thanks in advance.

Have a similar question here but no answer found 
[Xcode 7 update completes but Xcode 6.4 remains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880892/xcode-7-update-completes-but-xcode-6-4-remains)

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues like this before and found that deleting old Xcode and installing the new new one downloaded from Apple works better than using the Mac App store.

Once logged into developer.apple.com you should be able to get the 7.1 dmg from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ download that (http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.1/Xcode_7.1.dmg) and install from there.